Book about a scientist wrongfully convicted of murdering his wife being sentenced to die on a desert planet
I checked this book out from my local library a couple of times between 1985-1990 before it was cycled out. The library did not keep records once the books were retired so they can't help me.  The book was written no later than 1985.  It was in either young adult or science fiction.  The title was simple I believe, just one or two words.
The plot involved a scientist wrongfully convicted of murdering his wife being sentenced to die of exposure on a desert planet. He has amnesia or erased memory and the book starts with him being deposited on the planet.  He is rescued by, I think, a woman on a hover bike.  They go on to uncover a plot by the corporation the scientist did research for, where he was framed in order to cover up their activities.  At one point they break into his old lab to retrieve records and he uses a glove of "synthskin" to bypass a biometric security system.
That is pretty much all I remember, but I am pretty sure about the overall plot points, although I may be slightly off on order or specifics.
I can say for sure that it is not the book Prison Planet although some of the plot points are similar.  The book would not have been published later than around 1985.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you recall the cover at all?  Or the names of any of the characters?
